# Android Canvas - compress image with 80% quality but keep overlay text 100%

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, compression

I need to write text on image and save it as jpg format. I have to compress the image to 80% quality to reduce the filesize. The image itself looks good but the text on it doesn't look very attractive.

Is there a way to reduce the image part to 80 but keep the text part to 100 while merging? Thanks in advance.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Story.imagesPath.get(position));
newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), config);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

Paint bgPaint=new Paint();
bgPaint.setColor(bgColor);
Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
canvas.drawText(text, width/2, text_bottom, paintText);

File newFile = new File(dir, java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fileOutputStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  The compress function doesn't know anything about text.  It just sees pixels.  It can only compress at 1 quality level for the entire image.  If the image quality isn't good enough, up the quality or switch to losless encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can't there be any workaround to achieve that? Will saving them separately with different quality and merging them again with 100% quality could work?

Comment: You could.  You'd be adding a lot of complexity for very little gain that way.  I wouldn't do it unless you had other reasons to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Kept the quality to 80% but increased the bitmap dimension. That increased the text quality but still in a good filesize.